# Hide/Show header on scroll down/up using pure javascript with IntersectionObserver

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

We all know **headroom.js**, which is a great widget for showing / hiding the header when scrolling down / up. I would use this widget but my usage cases are slightly different.

I'm trying to build this now with an IntersectionObserver.
My root element is `null`, so it refers to the complete document.

```
  // Create observer with callback and config
  observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersect, config);
  // Observe .as-wrapper
  observer.observe(section);
```

My handleIntersect() function call sticky() which looks like this:

```
function sticky(target, entry) {
  let prevRatio = 0.0;
  console.log("call sticky function");
  if (entry.isIntersecting) {
    console.log('is interacting');
      if (entry.intersectionRatio > prevRatio) {
        console.log("Your are scrolling down! Hide Header!");
      } else {
        console.log("Your are scrolling up! Show Header!");
      }

    prevRatio = entry.intersectionRatio;
  }
}
```

The function sticky() is executed correctly. However, the Observer fires only 1x.

**What do I have to do to make the Observer invoke each time I scroll up or down?**

Is the IntersectionObserver the right choice here? What would a perfumed and clear alternative? The goal is to show or hide any elements depending on the scroll direction.

Comment: I would say a scroll listener is better suited for this. It actually does what you want, see the scroll direction, and not how (or if) visible element ABC is on the page.